# Text box content rendering in a new window using javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have a asp.net  textbox(textarea which is in a repeater  have single texarea for each record which are read only) I have button (open in new window) when i click on it the content of the text area needs to be rendered in a new window using javascript .
similar to experts exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misread the question the first time.

Here is a javascript solution:

```
function DisplayTextFromRepeater() 
{
    var text = '';
    var repeater = document.getElementById('MyRepeater');
    var inputs = repeater.getElementsById('input');
    var txtId = 'MyTextBox' //ID of textbox in repeater template

    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
    {
        if(inputs[i].type == 'text') 
        {
            if(inputs[i].id.indexOf(txtId) != -1) 
            {
                text = text + inputs[i].value;
            }
        }
    }

    OpenNewWindow(text);
}

function OpenNewWindow(message)
{ 
    var OpenWindow = window.open("", "newwin", "height=250, width=250,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no");
    OpenWindow.document.write("<html>");
    OpenWindow.document.write("<title>Title Goes Here</title>");
    OpenWindow.document.write("<body>");
    OpenWindow.document.write(message);
    OpenWindow.document.write("</body>");
    OpenWindow.document.write("</html>");
}
```